# Rails loop through two category id to make them into an order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, nested-attributes

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :jobs
  root 'jobs#index'
```

```html
index.html.haml
%body
 %nav.navbar.navbar-job
  .container
   %ul.nav.navbar-nav
    %li= link_to "All Creative Jobs", jobs_path
    - Category2.all.each do |category2|
     %li= link_to category2.name, jobs_path(category2: category2.name)
    
    %li.dropdown
     %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown","role" => "button", "aria-expanded" => "false"}
 
     %ul.dropdown-menu
      - Jobcategory.all.each do |jobcategory|
       %li= link_to jobcategory.name, jobs_path(jobcategory: jobcategory.name)
```

```html
show.html.haml

#jobs
 .job
  %h1= link_to @job.title,jobs_path
  %h4= @job.company
  %p= @job.description
```

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150430144236) do

  create_table "admins", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "admins", ["email"], name: "index_admins_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "admins", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admins_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "category2s", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end


  add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"

  create_table "jobcategories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "jobs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "company"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "jobcategory_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category2_id"
  end


  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

I have two separate category for a single job. I wanted to loop through two id. Two id represent to separate category and wanted to display them, when they are selected.

```html
class JobsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!,except:[:index]


 def index
  if  params[:jobcategory].blank? || params[:category2].blank?
   @jobs = Job.all.order("created_at DESC")
  else
   @jobcategory_id = Jobcategory.find_by(name: params[:jobcategory]).id
   @jobs =Job.where(jobcategory_id: @jobcategory_id).order("created_at DESC")
   @category2_id = Category2.find_by(name: params[:category2]).id
   @jobs =Job.where(category2_id: @category2_id).order("created_at DESC")
  end
 end
```

Updated: i have tried this code but still i am getting error NoMethodError in JobsController#index ,undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass , @jobcategory_id = Jobcategory.find_by(name: params[:jobcategory]).id

```html
class JobsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!,except:[:index]


 def index
  if params[:jobcategory].blank? && params[:category2].blank?
   @jobs = Job.all.order("created_at DESC")
  else
   @jobcategory_id = Jobcategory.find_by(name: params[:jobcategory]).id
   @category2_id = Category2.find_by(name: params[:category2]).id
   @jobs = Job.where(["jobcategory = ? and category2 = ?", @jobcategory_id, @category2_id]).order("created_at DESC")
  end
 end
```

Comment: When you say this `if params[:jobcategory || :category2].blank?` you probably mean this `if params[:jobcategory].blank? && params[:category2].blank?`

Comment: @Max Williams : I have two separate category for a single job, now how to view the job by two separate category , i am not sure how to do this ? .... I don't know  .

Comment: @MaxWilliams : Yes , i wanted to loop through jobcategory and category2 ,the problem is only jobcategory  is showing up and category2 is giving error `id' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information you have `@jobs` that is set two times in your else statement. Only the 2nd `@Jobs` will be taken into consideration unless you change your variable name.

And I agree with @Max Williams your `if params[:jobcategory || :category2].blank?` should be written the way he proposed.

If you want to loop through two attributes of `Jobs` you can do `@jobs = Job.where(["jobcategory = ? and category2 = ?", @jobcategory_id, @category2_id])`

Ressource: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where

> EDITED answer:

In your view you use `link_to category2.name, jobs_path(category2: category2.name)` and `link_to jobcategory.name, jobs_path(jobcategory: jobcategory.name)` but your this is not defined in your routes.
 Modify this in your routes:

```
resources :jobs do 
  get 'jobcategory/:name_jobcategory', to: 'jobs#index', as: :job_category
  get 'category2/:name_category2', to: 'jobs#index', as: :category2
end
```

Then in your view:

`link_to category2.name, jobs_path(category2: category2.name)` and `link_to jobcategory.name, jobs_path(jobcategory: jobcategory.name)`

needs to be replaced by:

`link_to category2.name, category2_path(category2.name)` and `link_to jobcategory.name, job_category_path(jobcategory.name)`

now you can grab `params[:name_jobcategory]` and `params[:name_category2]` for your controller:

```
def index
        if params[:name_jobcategory].blank? && params[:name_category2].blank?
            @jobs = Job.all.order("created_at DESC")
        else
            @jobcategory_id = Jobcategory.find_by(name: params[:name_jobcategory]).id
            @category2_id = Category2.find_by(name: params[:name_category2]).id
            @jobs = Job.where(["jobcategory = ? and category2 = ?", @jobcategory_id, @category2_id]).order("created_at DESC")
        end
    end
```

Comment: @Antonie thank you for your information , I have tried loop through two attributes but not working getting an error  `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Try again but reset the db and repopulate it for testing ! and can you post the error message?

Comment: @Antonie :NoMethodError in JobsController#index ,undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass ,@jobcategory_id = Jobcategory.find_by(name: params[:jobcategory]).id

Comment: The problem is that no record is found with your find_by in your code: `Jobcategory.find_by(name: params[:jobcategory]).id ` so it returns Nil. Given that no record is found you can not use the id method on a non existent record. Do you have existing Jobcategory records ? and if yes then your params[:jobcategory] are not returning a matching name and in that case you need to edit your question and show the view code so I can understand how the params get the input + if possible your db schema. Thanks. We gonna solve this thing.

Comment: I think I found your problem can you show me your routes first ? So I can edit my answer ?

Comment: I have updated my answer if it does not work please share your error message and show me the output or your `rake routes` because I may have miss something.

Comment: I havetried your update   :undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass ... pointing at  @jobcategory_id = Jobcategory.find_by(name: params[:jobcategory]).id
@category2_id = Category2.find_by(name: params[:category2]).id